# Load first columns from datagrid to textbox in c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagrid

Im begginer in c # and I try to do a spin code that I found on the net.

My worry is that I would like the value of the first line of the datagrid, automatically loads itself when launching the form in a textbox.

I have this code that works fine, but it does not display any value in the textbox if I do not click on a datagrid line.

The code :

```
namespace SQLiteTEST
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private SQLiteConnection connection;

    private String SQLSelect = "SELECT * FROM User";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=BddTest.s3db;Version=3;");
    }

    private void search()
    {
        dataGrid1.RowEnter -= dataGrid_RowEnter;

        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            connection.Open();

        SQLiteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = SQLSelect;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGrid1.DataSource = dt;
        connection.Close();
        dataGrid1.RowEnter += dataGrid_RowEnter;
    }

    private void dataGrid_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int ID = int.Parse(dataGrid1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        String Data1 = (String)dataGrid1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value;
        txtId.Text = ID.ToString();
        txtName.Text = Data1;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        search();
    }

    private void dataGrid_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("erreur");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form_programme = new Form2();
        form_programme.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void dataGrid1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void txtName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void txtId_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dataGrid_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

}

How could I make the first line appear in the textbox as if I was clicking on it?

Thank you in advance for your advice or sample code.

Regard.

Comment: did u trired row_selected event the same code or on row command event ?

Comment: can yo u try this event ?
    void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // code that happens after selection
    }

Comment: ty but dont work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method like this:

```
private object GetValue(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
{
    return dataGrid1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value;
}
```

> I would like the value of the first line of the datagrid, automatically loads itself when launching the form in a textbox.

Use that to get any value you need. In your `search` method, at the end, after the data is loaded into the grid, you just need to get the values from the first row:

```
// first row first column.
// Use TryParse if the value is not always a number. If always a number
// then Parse is good enough
int id = int.Parse(GetValue(0, 0).ToString()); 
string data1 = (String) GetValue(0, 1);
txtId.Text = id.ToString();
txtName.Text = data1;
```

Also use .NET naming conventions so your local variables should be camel case and your method names should be Pascal notation. `search` should be `Search`.

Comment: Sorry `int.Parse(GetValue(0, 0);` was a missing a `)`. I corrected the answer.

Comment: ty but visual srudio tell me : The overloaded method has invalid arguments. For this : int ID = int.Parse(GetValue(0, 0)); Strange wheb i try :         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var form_programme = new Form2();
            form_programme.Show();
            this.Hide();
        } thats work for form2 ???? But how i do just code to load first row from database to textbox ? There is not more simply to do ?

Comment: I made another edit and now it is `int id = int.Parse(GetValue(0, 0).ToString()); `

Comment: Ok your code works but i need to clic in datagrid to show in textbox.

Comment: Did you put the code in your search method like i mentioned in the question? And if you debug does the `GetValue` method return anything at that point?

Comment: Your code works great but i need to clic in datagrid to do.

Comment: That is not what I asked you. I asked: Did you put the code in your search method like i mentioned in the answer? And if you debug does the GetValue method return anything at that point?

Comment: Yes i do all what you tell me, but thats work like my code... About debug GetValue i dont know to do it...

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials like [this](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=7ab4z9u7Q_I) to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly i find how to resolve my problem !
Ill do this :

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=BddTest.s3db;Version=3;");
    search();}
```

Regard.